# How can i read string from text file and convert into a map in clojure?

Tags: clojure, seesaw

I am trying to use Clojure - Seesaw to read from a file and convert the string into a map (variables) so that I can use them to print to a GUI. Below is my current code:

```
(ns store.core
(:gen-class)
(:require [seesaw.core :as seesaw]))

(defn -main
  [& args]
  (seesaw/show!

   (spit "amovies.txt" "")
   ;(spit "amovies.txt" (pr-str [{:id 1 :qty 4 :name "movie1" :price 3.50}
   ;                             {:id 2 :qty 5 :name "movie2" :price 3.00}]) :append true)

   (spit "amovies.txt" "movie: Movie_Name\nprice: 5\nid: 1\nquantity: 2" :append true)

   (print (read-string (slurp "amovies.txt")))

   (with-open [rdr (reade "amovies.txt")]
     (doseq [line (line-seq rdr)]
       (println-str line)))
```

I am stuck figuring out how to read the string from amovies.txt line by line and then create a map with it. The desired output should be something like
movie: Movie_Name
price: 5
id: 1
quantity: 2

but in a way so that if I were to say, :movie, it would reference the name of the movie.

Can someone help? All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1

```
(def movies-as-map
  (let [lines (with-open [rdr (reade "amovies.txt")]
                (line-seq rdr))]
    (binding [*read-eval* false]
      (map read-string lines))))
```

## 2

```
user> (def movie
        (binding [*read-eval* false]
          (read-string 
           "{:id 1 :qty 4 :name \"movie1\" :price 3.50}")))

#'user/movie
user> (keys movie)
(:id :qty :name :price)
```

## Will work with this

```
(spit "amovies.txt" 
      (pr-str [{:id 1 :qty 4 :name "movie1" :price 3.50}
               {:id 2 :qty 5 :name "movie2" :price 3.00}]) 
      :append true)
```

## But not with this

```
(spit "amovies.txt" 
      "movie: Movie_Name\nprice: 5\nid: 1\nquantity: 2"
      :append true)
```

docs: https://clojure.github.io/clojure/branch-master/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/read-string

## Wrong args being passed to `show!`

It looks like your passing a ton of arguments to seesaw/show!.

The documentation states

> Usage: (show! targets)
>
> Show a frame, dialog or widget.
>
> If target is a modal dialog, the call will block and show! will
> return the  dialog's result. See (seesaw.core/return-from-dialog).
>
> Returns its input.

Comment: I tried using that, and I presume reade is actually reader but reader cannot be found and causes errors in CLI.

Comment: What version of Clojure are you using? It should be clojure.core/read-string

Also, what's the error?